# Reverse mapping in any library using styletron

Tags: css, reactjs, mapping, baseweb, styletron

I'm using baseweb, it uses styletron internally (https://styletron.org/). Is there a way to get the reverse mapping of classes which are generated by styletron ?
Basically I want the original classnames not the ones generated using styletron.

I tried looking in the documentation but was not able to found a thing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.